# Delay Specific IoTHub Messages

Tags: .net, azure, cloud, iot, azure-iot-hub

When sending a message to IoTHub to be passed down to an IoT device. Is it possible to tell IoTHub to delay the delivery of specific messages?

From looking at the Microsoft documentation I can see it allows you to throttle messages, however I am after being able to do this only for specific messages so unless my understanding of how the throttling works, it would not suit my purpose.

Is this built into IoTHub or would I need to control the timing of messages from within my own application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure IoT Hub has the capabilities to interact with IoT devices in bulk and at a scheduled time.
Have a look at more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-jobs).

For your scenario, you can create a job to execute direct methods on the specific devices and time. Note, that this is a sync invoked method on the connected device.

In the case, where your devices can be disconnected, you have to use an async communication known as Cloud-To-Device (C2D) Messaging at the service-facing endpoint. There is no capability to schedule a C2D message within the Azure IoT Hub. It must be done outside of the Azure IoT Hub using for instance a Service Bus Queue and Azure Function.